# Xcode 4.01 - Sqlite error when trying to copy database

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am experiencing an error when running my project in xcode4.

A couple of times it stopped when it was trying to copy the database to the build directory, telling me the sqlite-file isn't there. After restarting my Mac it now stops in the build process. The text above the info-progress bar tells me "attaching to [project]".

This doesnt happen when running my project with Xcode 3.2.6.

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Thank you very much in advance.

best regards

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Xcode is a bit more serious about what's really within the xcode-project, not just laying in the directory. The error means I forgot to add the file in the directory to the project again after I mucked around with it.
Now that the file was added to the project everything is working again.
I hope it saves a bit of time in case somebody else comes accross the same problem.